# WPF LiveChart how to remove White border of Piechart series

Tags: wpf, pie-chart, livecharts, borderless

I have a WPF-LiveChart(lvcharts.net) PieSeries Chart but it contains a white border .How can i Remove those white background .please see the Code

```
<lvc:PieChart  Visibility="Visible"  Name="TestCaseChart" Grid.Row="0"   Grid.Column="1" Series="{Binding SeriesCollection}" InnerRadius="100" Width="180" Height="180" BorderThickness="0"  BorderBrush="Transparent"></lvc:PieChart>
```

I tried the BorderBrush and BorderThickness properties but the Chart is not taking those properties.Basically my Screen background is black so it is awkward to see the white background on these charts series .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
  <lvc:PieChart LegendLocation="Bottom" DataClick="Chart_OnDataClick" Hoverable="False" DataTooltip="{x:Null}" ScrollBarFill="{x:Null}">
        <lvc:PieChart.Series>
            <lvc:PieSeries Title="Maria" Values="13" DataLabels="True"
                           LabelPoint="{Binding PointLabel}" Stroke="{x:Null}" StrokeThickness="0"/>
            <lvc:PieSeries Title="Charles" Values="4" DataLabels="True" 
                           LabelPoint="{Binding PointLabel}" Foreground="{x:Null}" Stroke="{x:Null}"  StrokeThickness="0"/>
            <lvc:PieSeries Title="Frida" Values="6" DataLabels="True" 
                           LabelPoint="{Binding PointLabel}" Foreground="{x:Null}" Stroke="{x:Null}"  StrokeThickness="0"/>
            <lvc:PieSeries Title="Frederic" Values="2" DataLabels="True" 
                           LabelPoint="{Binding PointLabel}" Foreground="{x:Null}" Stroke="{x:Null}"  StrokeThickness="0"/>
        </lvc:PieChart.Series>
    </lvc:PieChart>
```